# Playing one song after another results in horrible grinding noise; how can I fix this?

Tags: java, slick, music

I'm currently working on a game using slick2d java framework and I want to set it up so that the intro to a piece of music will play once, then the main body of the piece loops infinitely. I've got:

```
public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{   
    BossInt = new Music("OST/bossintronly.wav");
    Boss1 = new Music("OST/bossloop.wav");
    Boss1.setVolume(0.5f);
    BossInt.setVolume(0.5f);

    BossInt.play();
}
```

then in my update method

```
if (BossInt.playing() == false) {
        Boss1.loop();
}
```

It ends up playing through the intro once as intended, but then instead of looping the main body as I'd hoped it just blasts a horrible grinding noise. It's definitely not a problem with the wav file, I've checked and replaced that multiple times.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that you start the sound loop every time you call the `update` method.

To fix this, also check if the boss loop sound is currently playing and start it only if it is not:

```
if (BossInt.playing() == false && Boss1.playing() == false) {
    Boss1.loop();
}
```